# trying to pull an array value from a list of numbers but value comes back invalid array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I am trying to a pull array item number from a specific array.

for example if the input value has a number between 2.59 and 2.79 like 2.65

the output using this function

```
   const gpaToLevel = [].concat(...
        [1.99, 2.19, 2.39, 2.59, 2.79, 2.99, 3.19, 3.39, 3.59, 3.79, 4.00].map((ending, j, endValue) =>
            Array(ending - (endValue[j-1] || -1)).fill(j)
        )
    );
```

should be 4, because 2.65 is less than 2.79 and 2.79 has a value of [4].

thank you

Comment: Which array lengths do you expect, i.e. what are the expected values of `ending - (endValue[j-1] || -1)`? Currently, none of them are integers.

Comment: I am expecting in my example the output of 4 and when I worked with whole numbers the map.() function was working ending - (endValue[j-1] || -1) I am wondering when I do it with decimals why is there a problem

Comment: where is `2.65` in your whole array i can't see

Comment: @CodeManiac the value is a number between two array items and that is supposed to return the value of the array item that is higher than it so in this case 2.79 which is Array[4]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). It takes a callback and will return the index of the first item where the callback returns `true`.

So if your array is sorted you can use:

```js
arr = [1.99, 2.19, 2.39, 2.59, 2.79, 2.99, 3.19, 3.39, 3.59, 3.79, 4.00]

// 4
console.log(arr.findIndex(item => item > 2.65))
// 5 
console.log(arr.findIndex(item => item > 2.85))
// 0
console.log(arr.findIndex(item => item > 1.85))

// -1 -- no items greater than 4.0
console.log(arr.findIndex(item => item > 4.5))
```

Comment: I think you are right the way my data structure was layed out I think I just tried to concate the array items thanks